# How to search for a string inside an array elements using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, find, match

```
var objTittleArr= ["Game of Thrones", "Suits", "Breaking Bad", "Legend of Korra"];
```

How can i find array items includes a string?

I tried to find array items includes 'orr' as below. where am I going wrong? How can i find them?

```
for (var j=0; j<objTittleArr.length; j++) {

        if (objTittleArr[j].match(/orr/g))
        {
             alert(objTittleArr[j]);
       }
        j++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can keep in an array the matched element like:

```
var res = objTittleArr.filter(x => x.indexOf("orr") !== -1)
console.log(res); //[ 'Legend of Korra' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `j++;` after the `if`, it makes the loop increment twice each iteration, so you're skipping odd-indexed elements.

Also, just in case - Legend of Korra needs to be between quotes.

Comment: Thanks, so if you want case-insensitive, use `/orr/gi`

Comment: Use `/orr/gi.test(string)` if you don't need to retrieve an array of matches.